# How do I "request.user" in django shell

Tags: django, shell, django-models

I want to query my django User models on authenticated user on shell. How do I authenticate a user on shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your AUTH_USER_MODEL you defined in the settings.

If you have not touched to this, so it is the default User model and in your shell import the User class:

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

If you have edited the User class in one of your app, import this one (for example I have defined the User class in my app *home* `class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)`):

`from home.models import User`

I 'll go ahead with the first case (remove the 's' of 'objects' for the second case in the queries), so now you can do queries on the User class:

`User.objects.all()`

`user = User.objects.get(username="***")`

Now, import your authentication method, by default `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

And then, you can authenticate your user (the username arg depends on the `USERNAME_FIELD` of your User class):

`authenticate(username="*****", password="*****")`

`user.is_authenticated`  #True

Answer (score 0):

There is no `request.user` in the Django shell. `request.user` is assigned on the request you make to the View.

What you can do instead is assign a user from the User Model like,

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=1)
```

and then use this user to do whatever you wanted to do with `request.user`